Uint8Array too big to be converted to string
I'm trying to download a zipped csv-file, unzip it and parse it. Unfortunately, it seems like the unzipped file is too big (almost 1GB) to be converted to a string. What's the best way to split the data? Is it possible to create a stream that streams the Uint8array to a string which is then streamed and read by the csv reader (papaparse)?
This is my current approach:
const response = await fetch(url);
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const int8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
const unzipped = fflate.unzipSync(int8Array);

   
const csvString = fflate.strFromU8(Object.values(unzipped)[0]); // this throws an error
const readCSV = Papa.parse(csvString, {
  header: true,
  delimiter: ',',
  skipEmptyLines: true,
});

Thanks for any help!

It seems that Papa has built-in streaming functionality: "Specify a step callback to receive the results row-by-row. This way, you won't load the whole file into memory and crash the browser."
Have you tried that approach? In my browser it unzips downloaded file perfectly fine.

fflate supports streams.

Thanks for both suggestions. The problem however is the conversion from the UInt8Array to string. The string cannot exceed 500ish megabyte. I eventually figured it out: I can just split the UInt8Array into chunks ("10" indicating the end of a csv row, thus splitting the array into chunks that end on "10"). This worked.
